# Getting 401 error while trying to get access key for Twitter authorization

Tags: python, ubuntu, twitter, oauth

My code is as follows

```
import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = 'my_consumer_key'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'my_consumer_secret'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
print 'Please authorize: ' + auth_url
verifier = raw_input('PIN: ').strip()
auth.get_access_token(verifier)
print "ACCESS_KEY = '%s'" % auth.access_token.key
print "ACCESS_SECRET = '%s'" % auth.access_token.secret
```

When I run this script in the terminal, I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Twitter_OAuth.py", line 8, in <module>
    auth_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/auth.py", line 103, in get_authorization_url
    raise TweepError(e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

I searched on the Internet and I think it's something to do with the server time. But I can't seem to solve it.

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.10

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your code.
As you said, make sure your server time is close to the actual time. You can use a NTP daemon for this, which should come pre-installed on Ubuntu though.

Another reason for this error could simply be a typo in your tokens.

Answer (score 0):

oauth_verifier has been mandated . You should pass that when you are getting access Token.

-Vijay